# Exception class that catches many types of other exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I tried to make an exception class (lets call it EXP) that will be able to catch various types of other exception classes (for instance, std::exception), but without any success.
The main problem is that there are many types of exceptions that I need to catch, and I wondered if there is a better way than writing a macro that holds all the possible catches.

What I want to do (if its even possible) is something like that:

```
class EXP : ?? maybe must inherit ??
{
    // EXP implementation
}
```

EXP is defined in such a way that this is possible:

```
try
{
   throw std::exception("error string");
}
catch(const EXP& e)
{
   // catches the exception
}
```

So if it is possible, how can I define EXP so it will do what I want?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- first, it is generally a terrible idea to catch *every* exception type. Generally speaking, if you don't know what the exception *is*, how can you meaningfully handle when it occurs?
- second, *if* you want to catch every exception type, you can use `catch (...)`. However, this does not directly give you access to the caught exception object. To access the exception object you then have to rethrow and `catch` each specific type that you're supporting (this rethrowing and recatching can be done in a separate function, which may be a solution to your question).
- third, even this only catches C++ exceptions. Other errors, such as segmentation faults/access violations won't be caught by this. If you want to catch that kind of errors, you'll need to use platform-specific operations or language extensions.
- finally, type conversions aren't considered when catching exceptions. If an exception type `E` is thrown, then you can only handle it by catching `E` or any of its base classes. But you can't, for example, handle it by catching an exception that is constructible from an `E`.

Note: regarding the rethrowing scheme in the second point, it may not work with pre-standard compilers; e.g. it does not work with Visual C++ 6.0.

Comment: I thought that if you caught a `base&`, you could indeed catch a `derived`.

Comment: @Dead: yeah, true. Got my terminology mixed up a bit. Edited it. Better now?

Comment: Added info about the rethrowing scheme/idiom for catching multiple exception types.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to derive all of your exception types from `std::exception` (or its standard subtypes such as `std::runtime_error`); then you can use `catch (std::exception const &)` to catch anything thrown by your code, the standard library, or any other well-behaved library.